# Customizing Mapbox Callout with HTML on iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mapbox, callout

I am trying to implement a custom callout using `MapBox` on iOS.  When the user presses on the marker I would like a callout to display a `UIWebView` rather than a left and right accessory view and the title with text only.

I have searched through the SDK documentation and cannot find a simple way to access the view of the annotation title so I can set it to a `UIWebView`.

I started off by trying to access the annotation layer to see if I could make changes, such as:

```
RMAnnotation *annotation = [[RMAnnotation alloc] initWithMapView:mapView coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(56.0,-4.0) andTitle:@"test"];
annotation.userInfo = @"test";

RMMapLayer *layer = annotation.layer;
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

However, when I press on the marker the annotation bubble is still white.

I have searched through the SDK to try to understand the relationship between the `RMAnnotation` and `RMMarker` classes and how they interact but think my understanding is flawed and hence I am not getting anywhere.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out a way to make this work.  Its a little of a 'hack' but it works really well for my purposes so I thought I would share.  Please comment if you have a better idea and also tell me if this is not a great way to do it.

I checked the SDK source code and the `RMMapView` passes the `SMCalloutView` object the title, subtitle and left/right accessory views.  When I checked the `SMCalloutView` code there is the ability to provide a custom callout by passing a `UIView` to `contentView`, but the `RMMapView` doesn't provide for passing this.  My fix was to synthesize the `SMCallout` (`_currentCallout`) so that I can access `contentView` from my ViewController and set contentView to a `UIWebView`.  I chose to create a new delegate method in `RMMapViewDelegate` called `aboutToDisplayAnnotation` that provides me with the opportunity to swap in my `UIWebView` before the callout is drawn to the screen, but I guess a better way might have been to rewrite the `selectAnnotation` method in `RMMapView`.